# Open Email App only through intent in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I don't want to send `emails` to other users. I only want to open the `launching activity` of `Email`. I have tried it through different ways but every time send `email(compose)` is opening. **But i want to open `Email` app only nothing else(Sent, outbox, spam, Trash etc).**

My code is below

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
    .setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

//check if the target app is available or not

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Again, This code opens the `send email to`(compose) option. **But i want to open `Email` app only nothing else(Sent, outbox, spam, Trash etc).**

Comment: Hi, why your account is temporarily suspended? What did you do that this happened?

Comment: I got a chance to review questions after 500 reps. but I was skipping without any reason, this is what Moderator gave me the reason. lol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this code to open default Mail Application :

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
    this.startActivity(intent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What if I need to open other apps that are not very famous? do every app has category?

Comment: you need package name for that  see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/how-to-launch-an-activity-from-another-application-in-android